# how to enable automatic login in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, login

I have disabled my windows 8 lock screen but i would like to disable logging in altogether so that windows 8 automatically logs me in. If it is possible to disable lock screen, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/398015/how-to-disable-windows-8-lock-screen), then i'm sure there has to be a way of disabling logging in altogether but i don't just know how to. Can anyone help?

Comment: Also see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/472553/how-do-i-prevent-the-welcome-screen-lock-screen-from-appearing-after-idling-in) for lock screen disabling and enabling auto login.

Comment: @aditya if you feel that a question is a duplicate of another please use the flagging option instead. This will alert higher rep users and they can decide upon the action to take.

Comment: its not a duplicate. That question handles disabling the lock screen. I have disabled my pc lock screen. I even put a link on how to that in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter:

```
netplwiz
```

[image]

Uncheck the `Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer` check box and then hit apply.

[image]

This will bring up a dialog which will ask for your password, enter it and hit OK.

[image]

When you restart your PC next, you should be automatically logged in.

Comment: that's easier than typing "control userpasswords2"!

Comment: I wonder if having a Microsoft account changes anything. These are the same usernames, but one is local: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ywMEa.png

Answer (score 1):

Start the User Accounts settings by running `netplwiz` (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>). Uncheck the box

> Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer

[image]

[More information](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/09/16/windows-8-how-to-automatically-log-on/)

Comment: I press start and type run

Comment: Should be, "from the start screen type "run"

Comment: Changed back to `Win + R`

Answer (score 0):

On a related note if you need to enable auto logon on windows server - you need to set the following registry values. (This answer assumes that you are aware of the security concerns with enabling the auto logon on a server and still want to do it.)

Under HKLM\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winLogon key, set following reg values (all REG_SZ)
 1. AutoAdminLogon 1
 2. DefaultUserName
 3. DefaultPassword
 4. DefaultDomainName (for workground - I see this getting set to machine name)

restart the server. You can refer details [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310584). While link is for win2k server but it seems to be applicable to winserver 2012 also.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, it is the answer to a different question.  The appropriate way to provide this information is to write a new question, which you answer yourself (that Q&A format is fine on this site).