# In Windows 8, how do you disable the unlock password for Microsoft Accounts?

Tags: windows-8, password-protection

In Windows 8, in the scenario where there is a single user that has a Microsoft Account (i.e., they have created their account via a Microsoft email address) how does one disable the password prompt when unlocking the screen?

The Windows 7 analogy would be to disable the screensaver password prompt.

I can do this on a "local" account (one not backed by Microsoft) but the setting seems to have no effect on connected accounts.

To replicate:

1. create an account using whatever@hotmail.com or whatever@live.com
2. Lock the screen with WinKey+L
3. Attempt to unlock, by clicking the mouse, without entering a password.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions in [this](http://superuser.com/questions/495015/how-to-enable-automatic-login-in-windows-8) answer?

Comment: Dang I was trying to look for this but it seems that you've posted the answer anyways.

Comment: @tvStatic I have indeed, that will allow autmotic login at boot but not during an unlock.

Comment: Further, I would not like to disable the entire screen (as in answer #1 from second link), just the requirement for the password to log back in. I cannot currently test if that is what Answer #2 does from that link but I believe that procedure only works for local accounts and not connected accounts.

Comment: @Huckle: Alternatively you could set a PIN (4 digit code) for bypassing password login.

Answer (score 7):

To turn on automatic sign in for a local user account or Microsoft account:

1. press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run dialog box, then type in `netplwiz` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. select the user name of the local user account or Microsoft account that you want to have Windows 8 log on to automatically at startup
3. uncheck the "Users must enter a username and password to use this computer" box, and click/tap on OK
4. enter the password of the selected local user account or Microsoft account twice, and click/tap on OK

Comment: Other than adding detail, how is this answer different than the other posted answer; which I already indicated doesn't work.

Comment: @Huckle - These directions worked on my Windows 8 machine.

Comment: @Ramhound: By "worked", you mean that the password IS required to log in, but not to dismiss the screen saver?  Because that is what this question requires.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Microsoft account, utilize `netplwiz` in run, and disable the password, upon reboot your system then gives two options for signing in; a local account and the Microsoft account.  The local account will not require a password, but the Microsoft account does require a password.

To answer your question about disabling the password on a machine that is already running and you leave it unattended for some time, follow the directions in this article, which does work.
http://www.extremetech.com/computing/142482-how-to-disable-the-windows-8-lock-screen

Answer (score 0):

Disable the password using Run → `netplwiz`

This will disable the password prompt. Even with a Microsoft account.

Answer (score -1):

Goto Run (Win + R)
Open netplwiz 
You will get an option to disable the password prompt

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments on the question I have tried this and it works fine for *local* accounts but not for ones backed by Windows Live IDs.

Comment: @Aditya - This answer really needs some additional details.