# Is it possible to use a Microsoft account and don't log in with a password?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, login

I'm evaluating Windows 8 and there's something that's bothering me regarding the new user accounts.

First I used a local account instead of a Microsoft account for my user but to use some applications I do have to sign in with one so I set up one and moved to using a Microsoft account instead. I'm using the machine I have for personal use and there is no other users, so I didn't even set up a password for my account; but now that I'm using a Microsoft account every time I start the machine it prompts me for the password for the account.

Is there anyway to use a Microsoft account and don't log in with a password?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/495015/how-to-enable-automatic-login-in-windows-8

Comment: It should be posssible to simply link your local account to the Microsoft account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually had to try this out to see if it'd work with such accounts as it does with local ones. If you're the only user in your computer you could setup the automatic login for it.

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the run dialog.
- Enter `control userpasswords2` to show the following dialog:

[image: User Accounts]

- Un-tick "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer."
- Select your user and click OK.

[image: Password]

- Enter your password and accept, next time you boot you won't be prompted for the password.

But this would only work to login one account, as far as I know there's no way not to be asked for the password of an account, either it being local or not.