# If I disable password logins, are there any network login implications?

Tags: windows-8, security

If I disable logins (eg enable an automatic login [as described here](https://superuser.com/q/495015/87028)) do I open myself up to a host of remote attack possibilities?

I would prefer not to have to log in each and every time, but I don't want to leave my machine wide open either.

My machine is ethernet connected to a wireless router and can access my local homegroup, if this plays into any considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Autologin only affects *local* access.

Answer (score 0):

I have used AutoAdminLogon on my own machine for years.

My biggest worry is physical security, can anyone else (family members) use my machine.  (My answer is not worried.)  The only nagging thought is that I expose my password in the registry in order to get the logon to work automatically.

Once logged on with AutoAdminLogon, to me it's just the same as if I had typed my password, at that point there are no additional network threats. Incidentally, this actually brings a tiny benefit, keyboard loggers are not recording my password!