# Autologin a user (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, auto-login

Many users use just one main login for a windows 8 PC with no password and that one logs in automaticaly (user1).

In order to access files from windows 8 machine on Android or other Windows PCs, a separate second login with password is the easiest solution. (user2)

How can one setup autologin for user1 and keep user2 somehow very much in the background and never bother the main user.

Comment: It looks like this question was previously answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/495015/how-to-enable-automatic-login-in-windows-8

Comment: indeed. still, `netplwiz` == `control userpasswords2`

Answer (score 0):

on the run dialog type

```
control userpasswords2
```

click the user, de-select the box, apply and done.

note: if it doesn't work via run dialog, run it from an elevated cmd.exe

edit:

[image]

note2: image is outdated, UI is still the same-ish

Comment: That does have user account management information, but I don't see an auto-login option to enable.

Comment: @Llamanerds i edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have always prefered to use the Registry and AutoAdminLogon
Launch Regedit and navigate to:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winlogon 
Set: AutoAdminLogon = 1 (one means automatic, zero means off, normal logon.)
```

Actually, the key point is setting a DefaultPassword for the DefaultUserName.

```
Create a new String Value called DefaultPassword
Set: DefaultPassword = "YourPwd".
```

If you want to know more here is an article of mine about [AutoAdminLogon in Windows 8](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-autoadminlogon-registry.htm)