# Disable Use the Welcome Screen in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, login

In Windows 8, I want users to type his/her name and password instead of clicking on a user name and typing password. It is similar to disabling "Use the Welcome Screen" in Windows XP. Is it possible ?

Comment: See if this helps:

[Lock Screen][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/472553/how-do-i-prevent-the-welcome-screen-lock-screen-from-appearing-after-idling-in

Answer (score 0):

Welcome screen can't be disabled since Windows Vista. There's no Windows XP-like login dialog any more.

On the other hand, you can disable displaying user list. Start *Group Policy Editor*, `gpedit.msc`, expand *Computer Configuration*, *Windows Settings*, *Security Settings*, and double click *Interactive logon: Do not display last user name*. Then select *Enabled* and click *OK*.