# Disable Windows 8 Welcome Screen

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-registry

I am developing a WPF window based application that runs in full screen. It's intended to work like an embedded system so I don't want to show any Windows logo screen or other similar information to end users.

I modified the appropriate Registry settings to automatically login an admin user. This works fine in Windows 7 32/64 bit as well as Windows 8.

**I want to disable or change this Welcome Screen in Windows 8 or 8.1:** 
[image: I want to remove this screen]

I searched for some articles and tips and tricks but no luck.

I want to make this change using the Registry.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Winodows 8 should still automatically log you into the account.  Are you sure no indicating of a user login event is displayed in Windows 7?

Comment: @Ramhound I want to remove  default welcome screen ...

Comment: I don't believe its possible to disable the [screen](http://superuser.com/questions/666215/disable-use-the-welcome-screen-in-windows-8) in the screenshot. You have enabled a default account and configured the system to automatically log into that account? What group policy changes have you tried?

Comment: yes I enabled default account and config. systeam as to automacally and its works fine but when starting system I see the welcome screen above.

Comment: That is a placeholder screen for while the desktop session is loading, what should take it's place for the time between logging on to the OS and the desktop is ready to be displayed?

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the Logon UI is not possible on desktop or server operating systems in any way supported by Microsoft. At best, you could hack it away. Since it won’t speed things up, the screen would simply be blank during that time. Not exactly what you’d call user experience.

It *might* be possible with Windows Embedded.

This behavior also consistent with earlier Windows NT versions. They all have the Logon UI visible after early boot processes are finished.

[Here’s the relevant MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449309%28v=winembedded.82%29.aspx) about Windows 8.1 Embedded Industry. Apparently, you can get what you want simply by activating Custom Logon:

> By default, Custom Logon launches directly into the shell without displaying the sign-in UI when automatic sign-in is enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Open group policy editor(Run: "gpedit.msc")

Go to:

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization

Double click “Do not display the lock screen,” and select Enabled from the dialog that pops up. Click OK.

Comment: I want to change welcome screen in posted in qustion not want to disable lock screen.