# Disabling auto log off in Windows Server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote-control

I want to run GUI tests on my Windows Server 2012. So first I connect to my server remotely and then disconnect by using tscon:
`%windir%\System32\tscon.exe RDP-Tcp#NNN /dest:console` as described by here:
http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/72794/

The problem is if I don't do any tests for several minutes (15-30 mins) then it automatically logs off, so if I run my tests after that (which is through Bamboo), they don't run; however if I run them just after running that command above to disconnect then tests run fine. I also noticed that if I just run that command and then connect to the server again it doesn't have login screen; but if I wait for some period and then try to connect again then I get the login screen. I tried these methods before:
[How do I prevent the Welcome Screen / Lock Screen from appearing after idling in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/472553/how-do-i-prevent-the-welcome-screen-lock-screen-from-appearing-after-idling-in)

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're after the **Session Time Limits** Group Policy settings.

You can find them in the **Local Group Policy Editor** (gpedit.msc) under:

***Computer Configuration-Administrative Templates-Windows Components-Remote desktop Services-remote desktop Session host-session time limit.***

[image]

These policies control the time limits for various Remote Desktop Service sessions.

Comment: How should I configure these policies?

Comment: Enable them and set a value in seconds that you want to keep the connection alive for. For example, 24 hours is 86400 seconds.

Comment: I kept them no limit and it didn't work?